# linked list A tied to another B that ties back to A

Tags: c, linked-list

// 2 structures tied by pointers

```
 struct A_cust            // customer information, a double-linked list with another pointer
   {
    char cust_info [20];  // as an example
    A_cust *prevCust;     // prev customer record
    A_cust *nextCust;     // next customer record
    B_tran *point_to_B;   // to the list of transaction records
   };

 struct B_tran            // transaction records, a double-linked list with another pointer
   {
    char cust_tran [20];  // as an example
    B_tran *prevTran;     // prev customer transaction
    B_tran *nextCust;     // next customer transaction
    A_cust *point_to_A    // to the list of customer records
   };
```

The compiler doesn't know "B_tran" when it parses "A_cust"
If I place the definition of "B_tran" first then the compiler has no idea what "A_cust" is

Any ideas, Ernest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following declaration at the top of your code

```
struct B_tran;
```

**Edit**: This is called a forward declaration, you're promising the compiler that you'll get around to defining `B_tran` later. (Thanks Greg)

Comment: This is called a forward declaration.